# Create an editable HTML table

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to follow the prof's example of creating an editable table on double clicking an entry in a HTML table.  So my data method looks like this:

```
function formatData(message) {
    var str = "<table border=1>";
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        str += "<tr>" + "<td class='editable'>" + message[i].id + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + message[i].name + "</td>" +
                       "<td class='editable'>" + message[i].url + "</td>" +
                       "<td class='editable'>" + message[i].desc + "</td>" + 
                       "<td>" + "<a href='#' onclick='deleteRequest(this); return false' id='" + message[i].id +                                        "'>delete</a>" + "</td>" + 
                       " + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    }
    str += "</table>";
    return str;
}
```

I bind a function edit() to the  tags whose attributes are of class 'editable.'  Then my edit function does:

```
function edit(elm) {
  /* check to see if we are already editing */
  if (elm.firstChild.tagName && elm.firstChild.tagName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT")
    return;

  /* save original content */
  var orig = elm.innerHTML;

  /* create edit field */
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.value = elm.innerHTML;
  input.size = 20;

  /* convert content to editable */
  elm.innerHTML = '';
  elm.appendChild(input);

  /* position cursor and focus */
  if (input.selectionStart)
    input.selectionStart = input.selectionEnd = 0;
  else
    {
     var range = input.createTextRange();
     range.move("character", 0);
     range.select();
    }
  input.focus();

  /* set save trigger callback */
  input.onblur = function(){save(elm, input,orig);};
}
```

I'm confused on how I would save the information and pass it to the web server to update.  I need the id, url, and desc to update the web server.  Since they double click on a table entry, that just gives me the element at that value, but I don't have the id.  Do I change two lines in my formatData to:

```
"<td class='editable' id='" + message[i].id + "'>" + message[i].url + "</td>" +
"<td class='editable' id='" + message[i].id +"'>" + message[i].desc + "</td>" +
```

So that way I can ask the webserver for the url and desc with that id value?  That seems like a bad way to do it since now two  have the same id, but I'm not sure since I'm relatively new to AJAX, HTML, Javascript.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I kind of skimmed through this, but you can pull out the innerText of tag, not sure why you'd need to store it in duplicate on an id attribute of the cell.  Even so, why not id attribute on the row instead of the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh, I'll push a bit of help your way.

Basically, from what I gather you're binding a function to each `td` tag with `editable`.  Well, you can determine the id inside that function.

B/c you can select the `parentNode` of the current node being edited, and then select the `firstChild` of that parentNode, so `parentNode.firstChild` which should be the first `td`, since remember on each row each of your `td`'s will have a single parent `tr`.  Then you select the firstChild of that td node, which is the text node it contains, and then grab its value, the id.  So `parentNode.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue`

This might not follow exactly with your code, as you only show parts of it... but this is the gist of the idea.  Basically selecting nodes through the DOM and pulling the right one based on the current context.

I'd suggest playing around with it till you get it.

Here's a little bit of sample code for you to think about if you get stuck still.  It's meant to be brief.

Basically, each middle column is tagged with the `test` function on the `onfocus` event (clicking inside the input).  So it's on the input itself, and it pulls the parentNode `td`, then the next parentNode `tr`, then the firstChild of `tr` which is the first `td` then the firstChild of the first `td` which is the `input` on that row, then finally that `input`'s value attribute.

```
<script>
function test(elem) {

    alert( elem.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.firstChild.value );
}
</script>

<table>
<tr><td><input value="1"/></td><td><input value="stuff" onfocus="test(this)"/></td><td>other stuff</td></tr>
<tr><td><input value="2"/></td><td><input value="stuff3" onfocus="test(this)"/></td><td>other stuff</td></tr>
<tr><td><input value="3"/></td><td><input value="stuff2" onfocus="test(this)"/></td><td>other stuff</td></tr>
</table>
```